# Get select data from json file from external domain using vue js

Tags: vuejs2

I have below code to display list of cities from a json file. Json file is from an external domain.

Display.vue
HTML

```
 <select v-model="selected">
    <option v-for="option in results" v-bind:value="option.value">
     {{ option.text }}
    </option>
 </select>
 <span> Selected: {{ selected }} </span>
```

Script

```
 <script>
    import { axios } from 'axios';
    import Vue from 'vue';

     Vue.component('v-select', vSelect)

    export default {
       components: {
       }, 
       data() {
         results: []
       },
       mounted() {
         axios.get("https://test.com/data/cities.json")
        .then(response => {this.results = response.data.results})
      };
    };
 </script>
```

Is there anything I am missing in this?

Comment: What is the result of this code?

Comment: @YomS. error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined` and empty page.

Comment: Axios import should be like `import axios from 'axios'`.

Comment: @YomS. now, its just an empty page without any error. Function is not working

Comment: Please check your `data` object. It doesn't seem like it's returning anything, in fact the object is missing curly braces and a `return` keyword -- which should throw an error.

Comment: Let me know if that's not the issue here (perhaps only typos?).

Comment: @YomS.`data` object suppose to return data from the axios get function.

Comment: I know, can you first confirm that the above code is exactly how it is?

Comment: @YomS.the above code is exactly how it is.

Comment: Well, I kinda doubt it, the line where you define the `data` object is not even a valid object-returning function. As I said, it is missing curly braces and a return keyword.

Comment: What @Yom S. is trying to say is that your data should look like:
    ```data() {
      return {
        results: []
      };
    }```